# How do I set the OSearch14 Service Account via PowerShell

Tags: powershell, sharepoint-enterprise, fast-search, fast-for-sharepoint

I'm in the process of Scripting a deployment of SharePoint 2010 and FAST.

Normally to set the Service Account of a SharePoint service one would use the ProcessIdentity property, like so:

```
$procId = (Get-SPSearchService).ProcessIdentity
$procId.CurrentIdentityType = "SpecificUser"
$procId.ManagedAccount = $myManagedAcount
$procId.Update()
```

This works a treat for the `SearchService` object returned by `Get-SPSearchService`, however the `SearchService` object returned by `Get-SPEnterpriseSearchService` has an additional `ScriptProperty` that hides the `ProcessIdentity` property, and returns it as a string, rather than an `SPProcessIdentity`, which can't be updated.

So, The question:
Can I remove this `ScriptProperty`? OR
Can I change the service account via PowerShell without access to the `ProcessIdentity` Property?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You Need to Set the Managed Account Information and then Deploy for it to take affect.

```
$myManagedAccount = Get-SpManagedAccount -Identity "<Name of Account Here>"
$procId = (Get-SPEnterpriseSearchService).get_ProcessIdentity()
$procId.CurrentIdentityType = "SpecificUser"
$procId.ManagedAccount = $myManagedAcount
$procId.Update()
$procID.Deply()
```

Then this can be done after the Service has started  :-)

Comment: Good work mate, this code worked after I tried a few different things.

Answer (score 1):

You should use `.Deploy()` after `.Update()`

Answer (score 0):

Seems to be tricky

according to [this](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/jjameson/archive/2011/02/28/powershell-script-to-configure-search-in-sharepoint-server-2010.aspx) article :

> there appear to be missing one key piece: setting the default content access account to some service account other than the SharePoint farm account.

Comment: The article you linked does everything for setting up the FAST Search Service applications EXCEPT the bit I'm trying to do.